# What technology stack do Slack and Hipchat use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, chat

How do Slack and Hipchat handle chat on the server side and client side? What languages do they use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever I'm curious about the technologies used by certain companies I usually check their job postings.

Slack Application engineer job posting:

> Our main tools that we use to build Slack are PHP, MySQL, and Linux

Hipchat is a little more vague. They state throughout several job postings that they use PHP, Python, Redis, MySQL, ElasticSearch, and CouchDB. According to a [blog post](http://blog.hipchat.com/2011/02/03/whats-hipchat-made-of/) they use PHP for dynamic web pages, and python to implement a XMPP protocol for chat using Twisted.

So at the core it seems like they rely on a PHP/MySQL stack with some addition of other technologies.

Answer (score 2):

I like to check stackshare.io

http://stackshare.io/slack/slack

not a perfect answer to your question but a nice starting point[image: screenshot:]